# No textmenu in gparted?

Tags: gparted

Have a problem with Gparted as i can't partition my harddrive.
I can't get to a partitiontable because there is no textmenu to access, 
there are also a conflict with Udisks2 if that matters?

How do i get the textmenu to work?

Using gparted 0.30 on Ubuntu 18.04.

[image]

Comment: Pro Tip: Boot from a LiveUSB to work on your hard drive. Remember also that partitioning is dangerous - backup all your data before starting.

Comment: Have a empty harddrive i want to partition and have a hard time using USB.

Comment: Should i file a bug report on this?